# IndexOutOfBoundsException when removing ArrayList element

Tags: java, exception, arraylist

I have this code right here (using lwjgl but that should be moot) to try and pause a game when pressing the esc key. I use an ArrayList with the keys to keep track of what is pressed and what isn't.

```
public List<Integer> keys = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public void get() {
    if (isKeyDown(KEY_ESCAPE) && !keys.contains(KEY_ESCAPE)) {
        keys.add(KEY_ESCAPE);
        keyEscape();
    }
}

public void rem() {
    if (!isKeyDown(KEY_ESCAPE) && keys.contains(KEY_ESCAPE))
        keys.remove(KEY_ESCAPE);
}

private void keyEscape() {
    Screen.paused ^= true;
}
```

This is called by the loop, which does `get()` and `rem()` one right after another in the loop, in that order. This gives me an awesome `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1` at `keys.remove(KEY_ESCAPE);` when I let go of ESC.

Anyone have any insight to share?

Comment: Why not use `boolean` flags rather having  to check through the `ArrayList` every time? Seems unnecessarily expensive.

Comment: Consider using an `enum` for your key values instead of `Integer` values

Comment: Related to but not a duplicate of    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34643366/java-arraylist-remove-object-indexoutofboundsexception

Answer (score 6):

What is the value of KEY_ESCAPE?

It might be int with value 1 so instead of removing the object with that value, you remove the object at position 1 which apparently does not exist.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I fixed it by using `keys.remove(Integer.valueOf(KEY_ESCAPE));`. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

ArrayList.remove takes an int argument for the **index** where you want to remove your element. In your case, KEY_ESCAPE also happens to be an Integer.

In short you attempt to remove the Integer value of the escape key as the **index** of your ArrayList!